# Разница между NUMERIC и INTEGER

Tags: android, база-данных, sqlite, дата

Работаю с `SQLite` на `Android`. Допустим мне нужно сохранить дату и булево значение. в `INTEGER` прекрасно помещается `long`(мой `Date`), а булево не поддерживается, и конвертируется в 1 - 0. То есть оба типа данных спокойно помещаются в `INTEGER`.

Но во многих местах пишется что `NUMERIC` как раз для хранения даты, времени, датывремени и булевого значения. В чем разница ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Из документации](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#castexpr)

> Casting a TEXT or BLOB value into NUMERIC first does a forced
>   conversion into REAL but then further converts the result into INTEGER
>   if and only if the conversion from REAL to INTEGER is lossless and
>   reversible. This is the only context in SQLite where the NUMERIC and
>   INTEGER affinities behave differently.

Говоря русским языком, единственная разница между этими типами в том, что при преобразовании типа TEXT или BLOB в NUMERIC сначала происходит преобразование в REAL, а потом получившегося REAL в INTEGER, если таковое возможно без потери точности.